# Doctrine: Is this a relation or custom data retrieval?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, entity, relationships

I have an Entity called product, and it has (amongst others) two fields called Manufacturer and PartNumber. Another entity called SupplierProduct also contains those two fields (as well as others). When I retrieve a Product, I'd like to retrieve all SupplierProducts that have the same Manufacturer AND partNumber as the product being viewed and be able to access this collection via a field in the Product object.

Is this a doctrine relation (a one-to-many of some sort?), and if so, how would I set it up via annotations? If not, I assume I'd have to manually retrieve the data and set the collection of supplier products to the product? Importantly, Manufacturer and partno are not primary keys on the product entity, something they'd have to be for join columns to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, doctrine 2 does not directly support these sorts of compound relations.

You could create an ManufacturerPartNumberEntity with fields for product,supplierProduct,manufacturer,partnumber.  You could then use this entity to link product and productsupplier.  Be a bit of a pain to keep in sync and a bit redundant but it would allow for fast queries.

You might even be able to remove manufacturer and partnumber from your product/supplierproduct entities.  That of course will depend on exactly what all you need your model to do.

Just doing an additional query is probably your best bet overall.  Among other things, this would mean that products could be in one database and supplierproduct in another.

Comment: I've chosen to call another findby(array('manufacturer' => '...', 'part_no' => '...') to call the supplier products, but having to do this each time i want to create a product entity is annoying. am i able to overwrite all findby's in a custom repository to inject the additional query?

Comment: Not really.  But ask yourself why is it required that you load SupplierProduct every time you load a Product?  I suspect you could refactor your design. Redundant information should always raise a flag.

Comment: And after consideration, the refactor was really necessary, and the limiting factor. Thanks!